# Wordpress. Создание сайта

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужен простейший landing с блогом, на первой странице должна быть форма (прям в шапке сайта поверх фонового изобр). Возможно ли это выполнить без дочерних тем? если у кого то есть возможность скинуть ссылки на похожие темы или видео как делают такое, скиньте сюда пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще-то зря вы `wordpress` взяли для landing-page.. По-моему для лэндинга вообще не нужно cms. Простой сделайте страницу без всяких там систем управлений сайтами) А потом если заказчик требует какие-то изменения делать, то посмотрите на плагин `textolit`. Полезная шутка:)

Comment: в том то и дело что он требует на бесплатной теме в wordpress. Я всегда писал руками и для меня это темный лес))

Comment: Teryoshin, ну наверное без тем не получиться. Всё же надо сделать пустую тему и просто переделать под  неё сам сайт:)

Comment: Без [дочернЕЙ тмЫ](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) можно, но **не нужно**. Вне зависимости от выбранной темы. А леддинг морды сейчас в 90% тем. Только темы нужно брать из [оф каталoга](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите стандартную тему WordPress, например Twenty Seventeen (устанавливается по умолчанию). Поставьте плагин [Contact Form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/). Создайте в нем контактную форму.

Добавьте код в файл `/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php`. Посмотрите, какой шорткод плагин рекомендует добавить.

```
function action_wp_head(){
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="177" title="Контактная форма 1"]');
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'action_wp_head' );
```

Здесь `[contact-form-7 id="177" title="Контактная форма 1"]` - это шорткод, рекомендованный плагином.

Если хотите потом обновлять тему, надо создать дочернюю. Это довольно просто, инструкция [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

Comment: и он установит в хедер?

Comment: ну конечно, вы же видите - использован хук wp_head. Посмотрите на моем тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/shop/

Comment: спасибо , попробую - отпишусь

Comment: вы ничего не стилизовали? у меня не становится она сразу поверх

Comment: Вообще ничего не делал для стилизации. На сайте стандартная тема 2017

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, пугающимся МЕХАНИЗМА дочерних тем: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=Twenty+Seventeen

Comment: @SeVlad я испугался этих плагинов ) мне кажется, проще создать одну папку и в ней один файл style.css )))

Comment: @KAGGDesign, безусловно. И не только проще, но и гибче и в дальнейшем надёжнее и лучше. Однако в "ТЗ" - без дочек. Возможно, это какая-то новая мутация вируса плагинофобиии :)